# Running multiple process in parallel elixir

Tags: elixir

I am using `GenStage` and starting a few processes through it.

The code bit which is starting the process:

```
  defp start_snapshot_extractor(config, id) do
    config = Map.put(config, :id, id)
    case Process.whereis(:snapshot_extractor) do
      nil ->
        {:ok, pid} = GenStage.start_link(EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor, {}, name: :snapshot_extractor)
        pid
      pid -> pid
    end
    |> GenStage.cast({:snapshot_extractor, config})
  end
```

and in this module `EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor`

```
defmodule EvercamMedia.SnapshotExtractor.CloudExtractor do
  use GenStage
  require Logger
  import Commons
  import EvercamMedia.Snapshot.Storage

  @root_dir Application.get_env(:evercam_media, :storage_dir)

  def init(args) do
    {:producer, args}
  end

  def handle_cast({:snapshot_extractor, config}, state) do
    IO.inspect "here "
    _start_extractor(config)
    {:noreply, [], state}
  end
end
```

Now the issue is. I am using an endpoint to start this process with different configurations, sometimes with the same configuration.

When I first start the process it prints `"here "` and then after the completion of this process. it outputs `"here "` again, why is that the case? Instead of running both processes parallel why it's waiting for the first one to complete and then run?

Update:

this is how first method is being called

```
  extraction_pid = spawn(fn ->
    EvercamMedia.UserMailer.snapshot_extraction_started(full_snapshot_extractor, "Cloud")
    start_snapshot_extractor(config)
  end)
  :ets.insert(:extractions, {exid <> "-cloud-#{full_snapshot_extractor.id}", extraction_pid})
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a `GenStage` in the first place? The issue here is that the `GenServer` behind your producer is receiving messages from the process mailbox only upon the completion of previous `handle_cast/2. You need to start multiple instances, probably managed by `DynamicSupervisor`.

Comment: Yes you are right I dont need GenStage, may be, I am actually following already written code, and in that one, it starts multiple processes in the same way.

Comment: I also updated that how I am staring the first method anyhow.

Comment: Try to remove `name: :snapshot_extractor` from the call to `GenStage.start_link/3` only anonymous processes can be started that way; the named one would return `:already_started`.

Comment: if I change `snapshot_extractor ` it to `snapshot_extractor_anynumber` ?

Comment: It would probably work, but the code never calls the process by name, so why do you need to keep it?

Comment: I really dont know its just a bundle code of crap has already been written I have to follow the pattern, but if you can suggest something better? I am also updating question about a supervisor we have added to resume those process if application stop ans starts

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have just realized you indeed use the name in lookup. I’d post the answer with minimal changes needed to make it work.

Comment: Yes thanks. it would be very helpful

Comment: also there is an integer id in config, can we also concat it with `:snapshot_extractor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the only one message from the mailbox processed by each process at any time, even despite `handle_cast/2` returns immediately. The process would ultimately finish processing the previous message before accessing the one waiting in the mailbox queue.

The easiest solution requiring a minimal number of changes would be probably to add *id* to the process name so that new processes for new *id* could be spawned. Also, you don’t need a lookup by name, [`GenStage.start_link/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/gen_stage/GenStage.html#start_link/3) is smart enough to do that for you.

```rb
defp start_snapshot_extractor(config, id) do
  config = Map.put(config, :id, id)
  name = :"snapshot_extractor_#{id}"

  CloudExtractor
  |> GenStage.start_link({}, name: name)
  |> case do
    {:ok, pid} -> pid
    {:error, {:already_started, pid}} -> pid
  end
  |> GenStage.cast({:snapshot_extractor, config})
end
```

Comment: ` GenStage.cast({:snapshot_extractor, config})` id will be bind in this line too?

Comment: No, it receives `pid` as the first argument. `snapshot_extractor` there is a part of the message to cast. `handle_cast/2` would pattern match it to execute the respective clause.

Comment: we should use `Registry` to name your GenServer. Generating atoms at runtime is an antipattern as I already pointed out and will eventually crash the BEAM.??

Comment: That’s correct; without the context, I wrongly assumed there is  known in advance, relatively not too huge, the number of processes.

Comment: Okay, do you still think DynamicSupervisor is a better choice for this?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, at least without seeing your `Producer` and `Consumer`. `DynamicSupervisor` was explicitly designed to handle supervision strategies with dynamically changind children.